# Jenkins trigger builds due to fail polling

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins to push NodeJS project to Heroku. My project configuration has 2 git repositories setup, one is the source code and the other is heroku's app git repository.

The problem is that jenkins is polling on both repositories and when it fail to find the branch I'm looking for in the code repository is fails with the following error:

```
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision 1234 (origin/qa)
using GIT_SSH to set credentials Jenkins SSH Key
 > git -c core.askpass=true ls-remote -h git@heroku.com:my-app.git qa # timeout=10
[poll] Couldn't get remote head revision
Done. Took 3 sec
Changes found
```

As you can see it fail to find head revision for the heroku git repository and decide changes found.

How can I make Jenkins poll only on the source code repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've update my GIT plugin to version 2.4.0 and it seem to solve the problem.

Comment: Do you mean your `git` plugin?

Comment: @IdoRan You should change the plugin name in your answer